# Dictionary with keys of type 'integer' and values of type 'dynamic array of integers': Type mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba

I want a dictionary with keys of type 'integer' and values of type 'dynamic array of integers'.

The following code give me a type mismatch.

The first `if` statement sets up a dictionary with key=0 and array [0].
The second `if` statement tries to modify the key to have value the array [0,1].

```vb
Sub tester()
    
    ' prepare graph adjacency dictionary
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        
    Dim a() As Integer
    Dim ub As Integer
        
    If (Not dict.Exists(0)) Then
        ReDim a(0 To 0)
        a(0) = 0
        dict.Add 0, a(0)
    End If
            
    If (dict.Exists(0)) Then
        ub = UBound(dict(0)) ' type mismatch here ? why ?
        ReDim a(0 To ub)
        a = dict(0)
        ReDim Preserve a(0 To ub + 1)
        a(ub + 1) = 1
        dict(0) = a
    End If
      
End Sub
```

Comment: You add `a(0)`, which is an `Integer`, to a dictionary. You then retrieve it and try to treat it as an array.

Comment: @gserg so it should be dict.Add 0, a ?

Comment: Yes, it should be.